# Function iterates the same input received from text file

Tags: c, file, linked-list

This function should read a single line input from a file called `"newtext.txt"` (defined by path in my code), extract the first word in said line and use it as the name field for each element of a linked list (which is then printed).

This is code I wrote:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct user {

    char name[50];
    struct user* next;
};

int main() {

    unsigned i = 0;
    struct user *temp = NULL
    struct user *aux = NULL;


    FILE* file_pointer = fopen("/home/marco/Desktop/suite1/newtext.txt", "r");

    if(file_pointer == NULL) {

        printf("\nWarning! File not opened properly!\n");

        return -1;
    }

    char vector[100];
    char sub_v[50];

    while(fgets(vector, sizeof(vector), file_pointer) != NULL) {

        while(vector[i] != ' ' && i < (sizeof(sub_v) - 1)) {

            sub_v[i] = vector[i];
            i++;
        }

        sub_v[i] = '\0';
        i++;

        if(temp == NULL) {      //first element in the list;

            temp = malloc(sizeof(struct user));
            aux = temp;
            strcpy(temp -> name, sub_v);
            temp -> next = NULL;

        } else {

            temp -> next = malloc(sizeof(struct user));
            temp = temp -> next;
            temp -> next = NULL;
            strcpy(temp -> name, sub_v);
        }
    }

    while(aux != NULL) {

        puts(aux -> name);
        aux = aux -> next;
    }

    fclose(file_pointer);

    return 0;
}
```

the file included is:

```
andrew michael jonathan
frank
marcus raquis
freddie
```

And the expected output should be:

```
andrew
frank
marcus
freddie
```

but it is:

```
andrew
andrew
andrew
andrew
```

It appears the while cycle is repeated with the same imput line, but I don't know how to fix this issue.

Comment: "Read a single line input" and "first word in each line" sounds contradictory.  Do you mean "Should read one line at a time and extract the first word on each line"?

Comment: Style note: the dot `.` and arrow `->` operators bind very tightly and should not have spaces around them.  Use `structure.member` and `pointer->member` without any spaces.

Comment: Note `temp` is uninitialised in the first `while` loop so the result of the comparison `if(temp == NULL)` is undefined.

Comment: I'll fix it know, thanks.

Comment: `char vector[100];` -- don't skimp on buffer size. `1024` is fine and provides for all but the longest lines. `100` is easily exceeded. I'd rather be `10,000` characters to big that `1` character too small. (also, don't use *magic-numbers*, `#define` any constants needed, e.g. `#define NAMEC 50  #define MAXC 1024` and then `char name[NAMEC]; char vector[MAXC];`, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

The variable i is not reinitialized within the while loop

```
while(fgets(vector, sizeof(vector), file_pointer) != NULL) {
```

Thus the inner loop

```
    while(vector[i] != ' ' && i < (sizeof(sub_v) - 1)) {

        sub_v[i] = vector[i];
        i++;
    }
```

has undefined behavior.

Declare the variable i inside the outer loop. For example

```
while(fgets(vector, sizeof(vector), file_pointer) != NULL) {

    unsigned i = 0;
    while(vector[i] != ' ' && i < (sizeof(sub_v) - 1)) {

        sub_v[i] = vector[i];
        i++;
    }
```

And this statement

```
    i++;
```

is redundant and does not make sense.

And the condition in this loop

```
while(vector[i] != ' ' && i < (sizeof(sub_v) - 1)) {
```

it is better to substitute for

```
#include <ctype.h>

// ...

while( !isspace( ( unsigned char )vector[i] ) && i < (sizeof(sub_v) - 1)) {
```

Comment: `unsigned i = 0` is totally valid, but I would use `unsigned int = 0`.

Comment: @alrevuelta Use!:)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so what happened here is you forgot to set variable ' i ' to 0 in the beginning of the while loop.

The first time the loop runs it works just fine, the first line  is written into the arrray *vector*, the first word is copied into *sub_v* and into the node's *name* variable.

The array *sub_v* now looks something like this:

```
['a', 'n', 'd', 'r', 'e', 'w', '\0', (garbage values), ...]
```

But then - on the next iteration, since ' i ' wasn't set back to 0, garbage values were copied from the *vector* to the end of *sub_v* (after the '\0').

The reason why the output was the word "andrew" 4 times is because when this line was executed:

```
strcpy(temp->name, sub_v);
```

It only copied the characters until the terminating null byte '\0', because thats how strcpy(3) works (copies a string). The '\0' indicates the end of the string, everything after it is not treated as part of the string.

So the start of the array *sub_v* was printed every time ("andrew"), which made you think the problem was with fgets cycling the same line, but the source of the problem was not setting the ' i ' variable to 0 at each loop iteration.

Btw, its good that you checked the return value of fopen and also closed the file at the end, you should do the same thing with *malloc(3)*, and don't forget to free the memory that you have allocated for each node.

Comment: This was very helpful, I thought the same input was used over and over again, but actually the input changes but the string array isn't reset, so the output doesnt change